# How implement doubling point using VHDL language

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptographic-hardware

I have a problem with my implementation. I want to make a multiplication in finite field. I don't know If my scheme is correct, but I made code on this base. I want to calculate: 
D= X*Y
D=D*X
[image]

[image]

Some Code
https://drive.google.com/open?id=186i8K6PMduY2UsBdpPmdm3WmrjBWYQtj

Comment: I don't believe this site can answer your question. You may want to look at [electronics.se].